# How to remove conntrack modules?

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

I tried to remove conntrack modules by conntrack -D but it is not removed.
The list of contracks that I want to remove is :

```
  # conntrack -L |grep 192.168.2.210
  tcp      6 1 LAST_ACK src=192.168.2.210 dst=192.168.2.28 sport=53123 
  dport=47778 src=192.168.1.214 dst=192.168.2.210 sport=47778                dport=53123 [ASSURED] use=1
 conntracktcp      6 431999 ESTABLISHED src=192.168.2.210      dst=192.168.2.28 sport=53125 dport=20900 src=192.168.1.214      dst=192.168.2.210 sport=20900 dport=53125 [ASSURED] use=1
 v1.4.3 (conntrack-tools): 110 flow entries have been shown.
 tcp      6 431971 ESTABLISHED src=192.168.2.210 dst=192.168.2.28      sport=53122 dport=21 src=192.168.1.214 dst=192.168.2.210 sport=21      dport=53122 [ASSURED] helper=ftp use=2
 tcp      6 431979 ESTABLISHED src=192.168.2.210 dst=192.168.2.28      sport=53124 dport=21 src=192.168.1.214 dst=192.168.2.210 sport=21      dport=53124 [ASSURED] helper=ftp use=2
```

I runned conntrack -D and conntrack -F and I get

```
 conntrack v1.4.3 (conntrack-tools): connection tracking table has been emptied.
```

I runned conntrack -L again I get the following lines

```
# conntrack -L |grep 192.168.2.210
conntrack v1.4.3 (conntrack-tools): 27 flow entries have been shown.
tcp      6 431996 ESTABLISHED src=192.168.1.214 dst=192.168.2.210     sport=20900 dport=53125 src=192.168.2.210 dst=192.168.2.28 sport=53125     dport=20900 [ASSURED] use=1
```

I need to remove this line from conntrack

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Well sorry you asked it first but i saw it after, and your question has a few misleading words: it seems you want to remove conntrack entries, not the conntrack (kernel) modules. The (kernel) modules can't really be removed if you're using stateful firewalling (especially with helper modules for FTP) or NAT. Anyway, check this question and the answer I made: https://superuser.com/questions/1258689/conntrack-delete-does-not-stop-runnig-copy-of-big-file/1259201

Comment: In fact I meant by conntrack module current conntrack. Otherwise thanks for the anwser.