# Undo iptables DNAT/MASQUERADE rules and cut existing forwarded connections

Tags: linux, iptables

I have a machine where incoming TCP connections are forwarded to an external IP via these iptables rules:

```
$ sudo -n /sbin/iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 3306 -i eth0 -j DNAT --to 1.1.1.1:3306
$ sudo -n /sbin/iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp --dport 3306 -d 1.1.1.1 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
$ sudo -n /sbin/iptables -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 3306 -I INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
```

My issue is that I would like to undo these rules and drop all forwarded connections so that clients reconnect to the current machine. I've removed and flushed the iptables rules (so `iptables -S` comes back clean), and have tried removing the associated connections via `conntrack -r 1.1.1.1 -D` (and a bunch of entries are in fact deleted), but the connections keep getting reestablished. I've tried the solution given in [conntrack delete does not stop runnig copy of big file](https://superuser.com/questions/1258689/conntrack-delete-does-not-stop-runnig-copy-of-big-file) but seemingly to no avail.

What am I missing (or doing incorrectly)?

Comment: Do the re-established connections still get NATed to the same host? Have you verified that the iptables NAT rules (as opposed to just filter rules) got removed?

Comment: Ugh, that was it - forgot to remove the NAT rules. Thanks!